# Pass variable from VueJS to Controller of another application

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

i have to application:
Back-end : with spring boot run on localhost:8080
Front-end : contain vueJs run on localhost:8081
i want to pass a variable from my front-end vueJs and read it in the back end spring boot, any help? thx

Answer (score 0):

Just do an XHR request like you would to contact any server.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing data between Frontend and Backend requires a communication channel. Most popular way is to write a GET/POST API into the server and make a REST call from the client.

1. You need to write an API in spring boot server (Ex: http://localhost:8080**/INeedData** )
2. Make XHR or Axios or HTTP GET/POST request from VueJS passing the variable as Body to the API

Refer: 
https://www.journaldev.com/21127/spring-boot-rest-example
https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/